# Projection properties in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $L$ and $M$ be closed subspaces of a Hilbert space $H$ and $P_L,P_M\in \mathcal{L}(H,H)$ are orthoprojections to $L$ and $M$. I want to prove that then
$$P_M\geq P_L \Leftrightarrow L\subset M.$$

Partial order $P_M\geq P_L$ is defined as
$$P_M\geq P_L \Leftrightarrow ((P_M-P_L)x,x)\geq 0 \ \ \ \forall x\in X.$$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that a projection $P\in\mathcal L(H)$ is self-adjoint iff $P$ is an orthogonal projection. For if $P^2=P$ and $\ker P\perp P(H)$, then for $f,g\in H$ we have
\begin{align}
\langle Pf, g \rangle &= \langle Pf, Pg + (g - Pg) \rangle\\
&= \langle Pf, Pg \rangle\\
&= \langle Pf + (f-Pf), Pg \rangle\\
&= \langle f, Pg \rangle,
\end{align}
so that $P=P^*$. (The converse is not necessary for this exercise so I will omit the proof.)

Suppose $P_M-P_L$ is a positive operator and let $f\in L$ be nonzero.  Then $P_Lf=f$, so 
$$0\leqslant \langle (P_m-P_L)f,f\rangle=\langle P_mf-f,f\rangle.$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
\|P_Mf-f\|^2 &= \langle P_M-f,P_Mf-f\rangle\\
&= \langle P_Mf-f, P_Mf\rangle - \langle P_Mf-f, f\rangle\\
&\leqslant \langle P_Mf-f, P_Mf\rangle\\
&= \langle P_Mf,P_Mf\rangle -\langle f,P_Mf\rangle\\
&= \langle f, P_M^2f\rangle -\langle f,P_Mf\rangle\\
&=0,
\end{align}
and hence $P_Mf=f$, that is, $f\in M$.